# Adobe Air - Transparent stage

Tags: air, transparent, stage

Is it possible to change the stage of an Air 2.5 desktop application from normal to transparent at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can only define it once for each window (in xml descriptor for the main window and as init options for the new windows you create).